# How to split an image too large to be opened?

Tags: image, split

I would like to split large pictures, but they are two big to be opened for my GPU. Max JPEG size i can *completly* open is over 35Mo and 150,000,000px, with any program tried, using almost all resources. Windows affords opening heavier images after resizing them, so actually there is no more difference between 20Mo and 200Mo pictures on screen. Usual image editors do not try to resize them but they get my computer crash. The only way i found to open *completly and safely* is into.. a browser.

I also found two useful websites for online splitting but none of them handles pictures larger than 20Mo.

> how can one split an image when it is too large to be opened, even on specialized websites ?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image - width x height? When you say `split` do you mean you want say the top half in one file and the bottom half in another file?

Comment: Dimensions are 21600x21600, there are series of 6 pictures of these dimensions. Yes, precisely i would like to split each one in 10x10 other pictures.

Comment: If you can install `imagemagick`, you could try its [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) command to `-crop` the image repeatedly, chipping out desired parts.

Comment: You could do this programmatically using [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net) - specifically, via the `ilLoadImage()` / `ilBlit()` / `ilSaveImage()` functions. The first can be used to load an image file, the second to copy a sub-region into an "output" image, and the third to save the "output" image as a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would use Chrome or anything web-based, as your uncompressed image is going to require 3+GB of RAM to decompress and get started on.

I would use ImageMagick like this:

```
convert -crop 10x10@ input.png +repage out%02d.png
```

that will get you 100 tiles, each 2,160 pixels square, called `out00.png` to `out99.png`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice and for this command, you saved me few days. I was able to create tiled maps for lots of my pictures, however my laptop still definitely stalls on first files. I can split images until 23Mo (stall limit) in 21600x10800, but not 21600x21600 even at 19,5Mo. Is there a method to leave aside the input size ? I mean i first was interested with much bigger images, 80Mo, 200Mo : is it possible to edit them with a *normal* computer or are my resources limit the final problem ? That is why i was dreaming of a web solution were one's computer might not be a problem

Comment: If you install a version of ImageMagick with 8-bit quantisation (Q8) rather than 16-bit (Q16) you will be able to handle images that have twice as many pixels - i.e. each side is 1.414 times (sqrt(2)) longer. Downside is you will be able to handle fewer colours.

Comment: Thanks, you made me understand quite better whats is happening. My laptop will live longer and i hope i'll get a nice app :)